# Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: android, sql, http, mysqli, okhttp

I'm a begginner with android studio and I'm trying to make an application that makes HTTP requests. For that, I'm using OkHttpClient class.

This is the function where we make the request for the log in:

```
public void ok_login(final String num, String pass, final Handler mhandler) {

    view.showLoadingDialog();


    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(Constants.apilink + "users/login.php").newBuilder();
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("contact", num);
    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("password", pass);
    String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    //Setup callback
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            view.showError();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
            final String res = response.body().string();
            mhandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        JSONObject ob = new JSONObject(res);
                        Boolean success = ob.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success) {
                            JSONObject o = ob.getJSONObject("user_id");
                            String id = o.getString("id");
                            String name = o.getString("name");
                            view.rememberUserInfo(id, name, num);
                            view.startMainActivity();
                            view.dismissLoadingDialog();
                        } else {
                            view.showError();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                }
            );
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that the answer given to this request (using mysqli_connect_errno()) is:

Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO).

I know that I'm not using nor user nor password, but I dont really know how to set them.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:

[PhpMyAdmin Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jU3IX.png)

[SQL connection file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t8mC.png)

[Login.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YszK.png)

Comment: could you access your db from username and password you provided in android?

Comment: try getting response from `users/login.php` first on postman and then hit it in android

Comment: I have a db in phpmyadmin that is connected to the android proyect through an API that I have created. But I dont have the credentials in the android proyect I think.

Comment: you dont need to setup anything on android , its purly issue of your php script , try hitting on postman it will show you same error

Comment: When I try to make the request at Postman it returns a blank, and the error is return because of the function that we've set.

Comment: Make sure both are in same network & internet permission is given

Comment: I'm not sure if you're refering to that, but I've set already the internet permissions at Android's Manifest, and what do you mean with both?     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Answer (score 0):

you need to go to your phpMyAdmin and check if you have user account 'root' and set the privileges accordingly. See following snapshot [image: User Accounts]

Comment: its not root user its `localhost`

Comment: when you connect to mysql in php, you need to provide username and password like this; $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "shop");

Comment: if you can please share screenshot

Comment: I have just added some useful screenshots to the question.

Comment: yes, i have seen them, is your phpmyadmin on your local server or online?

Comment: The phpmyadmin is online.